# Specifying orthogonality condition

Tags: expression-manipulation

I am working with a calculation that involves testing many cases.

I would like to have some function that specifies certain orthogonality relations: Variables `bv` and `ev` are orthogonal, and so are `bv` and `tv`. So, their products would yield zero. How could this be implemented? Ideally, it would be a function to be applied to an expression, not a global setting for the document.

This must have been asked before, but I could not find a similar question to this.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
foo[a_, b_, c_] := Simplify@Total[Times @@@ Subsets[{a, b, c}, {2, 3}]]
foo[a, b, c]
```

> b c + a (b + c + b c)

```
foo[ev, bv, tv]
```

> bv tv + ev (bv + tv + bv tv)

```
Simplify[foo[ev, bv, tv], 
 Assumptions -> {Times @@ Cross[ev, bv] == 0, Times @@ Cross[tv, bv] == 0}]
```

> ev tv

Or set the value of `$Assumptions`:

```
$Assumptions = {Times @@ Cross[ev, bv] == 0, Times @@ Cross[tv, bv] == 0};
foo[ev, bv, tv]
```

> ev tv

**Update:** The example mentioned in the comments

```
Simplify[ev^2 Cos[f]^2 - 2 bv ev Cos[f] Sin[f] + bv^2 Sin[f]^2]
```

gives

> (ev Cos[f] - bv Sin[f])^2

as the input is simplified to `(ev Cos[f] - bv Sin[f])^2` before the term `ev bv` is replaced with `0`. To prevent this from happening, you can wrap the expression with `Unevaluated` before `Simplify`ing:

```
Simplify/@Unevaluated[ev^2 Cos[f]^2 - 2 bv ev Cos[f] Sin[f] + bv^2 Sin[f]^2 ]
```

> ev^2 Cos[f]^2 + bv^2 Sin[f]^2

as desired.

Comment: One problem: the expression `ev^2 Cos[f]^2 - 2 bv ev Cos[f] Sin[f] + bv^2 Sin[f]^2` gives `(ev Cos[f] - bv Sin[f])^2` instead of the desired `ev^2 Cos[f]^2 + bv^2 Sin[f]^2`.

Comment: @Rethliopuks, `$Assumptions = {Times @@ Cross[ev, bv] == 0, 
   Times @@ Cross[tv, bv] == 0};
Simplify[ev^2 Cos[f]^2 - 2 bv  ev Cos[f] Sin[f] + bv^2 Sin[f]^2 ]` gives `(ev Cos[f] - bv Sin[f])^2`

Comment: Yes -- but it should be `ev^2 Cos[f]^2 + bv^2 Sin[f]^2`. Because `(ev Cos[f] - bv Sin[f])^2` contains a cross term `-2 bv ev Cos[f] Sin[f]` that should be zero.

Comment: @Rethliopuks, right. Will update if i can find a fix.

Comment: @Rethliopuks, right. Looks like `ev bv` disappears before the assumptions take effect.  Not as clean but `Simplify[ev^2 Cos[f]^2 - 2 bv  ev Cos[f] Sin[f] + bv^2 Sin[f]^2 , 
 ExcludedForms -> {_Power}]`  does give `ev^2 Cos[f]^2 + bv^2 Sin[f]^2`

Comment: @Rethliopuks, please see the update.